# Raise exception on multiple specific "strings", python

Tags: python

I have a file which contains:

XYZname_1

XYZname_2

XYZname_3

In my script I am using a re.search to check if the names are incorrect, if they are I do a `raise exception`. If both names are incorrect it will only raise exception on the first on and then "crash", in other words the "user" won't know if the second or third name is incorrect.

```
for my_file in args.cpath:
    contents = open(my_file).read()

    replaced_contents = my_func(contents,my_file)


def my_func(my_file_contents, filename):
    for x in range(0, 3):
        #Some code here which is not related to the problem

        #In this if-statement I check if it does not match with re.search
        #I assume a for-loop should be here? but not sure how to implement it. 
        if not re.search(r'(.*)XYZname_{0}\(\)\) = .*;(.*)'.format(x+1), my_file_contents):
            raise Exception("The name: XYZname_{0} was not found".format(x+1) + " in " + filename)
```

Lets say the names we saw before are written like this in a file(they are wrong)

XYZnameHE_1

XYZnameGJ_2

XYZnameAsd_3

Then my script should tell me it can't find XYZname_1,2 and 3 in the given file.

Of course there could be other names as well, which another function takes care of. These names could start with XXXname_1,2 3 etc. And if one of them are missing i should get an exception for that one as well

Right now I get this output:

```
Exception: The name: XYZname_1 was not found in C:\Path
```

But I would like something like this:

```
Exception: The name: XYZname_1 was not found in C:\Path
Exception: The name: XYZname_2 was not found in C:\Path
Exception: The name: XYZname_3 was not found in C:\Path
Exception: The name: XXXname_2 was not found in C:\Path
```

Don't know what the "best practice" is for solving this. One option is to let the script finish looking through the whole file and then "crash"/raise? Or just "crash"/raise directly when it finds an issue? Because it would be annoying for the developer to run the script multiple times in order to find all misisng/wrong names.

Comment: Why not store the missing names in a list and then raise at the end if the list has any items in it?

Answer (score 1):

Collect the names/matches in a list. Then, after the loop, raise an exception if necessary. You also need `findall()` instead of `search()` from what I understand.

At the end you would have something like:

```
matches = []
for x in range(0, 3):
     #Some code here which is not related to the problem

     # add the matches to the list
     matches.extend(re.findall(r'(?:.*)(XYZname_{0})\(\)\) = .*;(?:.*)'.format(x+1), my_file_contents))

if matches:
    for match in matches:
        print("The name: {0} was not found in {1}".format(match, filename))
    raise Exception(...)
```

I've also replaced the `()` with `(?:)` in your expression - replaced capturing groups with non-capturing. Also added `()` around `XYZname_{0}` to capture the name.

Comment: Hmm I tried this out but my test pass as green even though the names are wrong.

Comment: @gants could be a problem with the expression. I think you might need to use the `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE` flags. And you may avoid the `(?:.*)` parts at the beginning and the end of the pattern.

Comment: Likes this? `matches.extend(re.findall(r'(?:.*)(XYZname_{0})\(\)\) = .*;(?:.*)'.format(x+1), my_file_contents), re.MULTILINE, re.DOTALL)`If I add like that it tells me they are "unexpected arugment"

Comment: @gants okay, try smth like `matches.extend(re.findall(r'(XYZname_{0})\(\)\) ='.format(x+1), my_file_contents), re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)`.

Comment: I think the issue is due to `matches.extend`can only take 1 argument and not 2

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch on each item in your iteration instead of a single pass:

```
for x in range():
    try:
        re.search ...
    except:
        raise exception ...
```

Not a python expert but from a pure code/logic perspective that should do the trick.